# Declare type having one required property and the rest should be dynamic and optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How would one define a type for an object that should have just one required property and the rest should be dynamic and optional (not know beforehand that is)?

Typical example and action in Redux - should have `type` prop and the rest is dynamic and optional.

Comment: By dynamic, do you mean of `any` type?

Comment: prop with any name and type - yes.

Comment: Is there a fixed number of such props, are their names known at compile-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should satisfy the specification, although I am unsure how to interpret "dynamic [...] (not know beforehand that is)".

```
type MyType = {
    requiredProp: string;
    optionalDynamicProp1?: any;
    optionalDynamicProp2?: any;
}
```

If by dynamic you mean any number of props of `any` type, this may be closer:

```
type MyType = {
    requiredProp: string;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```